# Make SAS export the code itself into an EXCEL sheet

Tags: export, sas

Often I have to write individual SAS programs for various demands where the final output is an EXCEL file. For the sake of reproducibility I often copy and paste the SAS code into a separate EXCEL sheet -- so it is easy to get back to the point when there is a similar request or the need for modifications.

Now I am wondering if there exists a way to make SAS export the current code into an EXCEL sheet in an automated way. Such a task is probably easier if the SAS code has been saved as a physical file on the hard-drive (so it not only exists in the working memory) -- so let us assume that this was indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

If the program has been saved as a file, then you can read it into a dataset (the same way you read any other file) and export that dataset to Excel.  It's up to you how exactly you do both of those things, SAS gives you lots of options.

As far as telling which program is executing, it varies by how you're running things.  If you are using DM SAS and the Enhanced Editor, you can use this code:

```
%let filename= %sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)\%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME);
%put &=filename;
```

and now `&filename.` holds the current program's path and filename.

If you're running in batch, you have to use the environment variable SYSIN.  Other modes have different methods, and it's not always possible (such as if you're in an embedded program in an EG project).  See [this doc page](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/301.html) for more details.